# how to use ASIHTTPRequest reachability

Tags: iphone, ios, asihttprequest, reachability

I am using ASIHTTPRequest to send requests to my php scripts that are then searching my mysql server, however I have read in apple documentation we have to implement reachability when ever we try to send or receive data over TCP...

What I am wanting to know is ASIHTTPRequest taking care of Reachability for me, or do I have to implement some method calls into my code to make sure the checking is being done?

any help would be great... ASIHTTPRequest documentation is abit light with regards to reachability and I have not been able to find any notes on what to actually do with regards to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [Google Group](http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest) that is better equipped to answer ASIHTTPRequest questions.

Since it's a reimplementation of iOS functionality, it's not particularly iOS relevant.